# Unable to start a QML app using qmlviewer/qmlscene

Tags: 13.10, application-development, qml

I'd like to start writing QML applications. I followed this tutorial: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-tutorial1.html

my code is:

```js
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: page
    width: 500; height: 200
    color: "lightgray"

    Text {
        id: helloText
        text: "Hello world!"
        y: 30
        anchors.horizontalCenter: page.horizontalCenter
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
    }
}
```

But I have the following error when I run it using `qmlviewer`:

```
qmlviewer: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlviewer': No such file or directory
```

I tried several qml launchers in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/`,

`qmltestrunner` returns:

```
FAIL!  : qmltestrunner::tst_ubuntutestcase::compile() module "QtTest" is not installed
```

and `qmlscene` fails with:

```
qmlscene: 'import QtQuick 1.0' is no longer supported.
Use qmlviewer to load file 'hello.qml'.
```

How I'm supposed to run this tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct launcher for simple qml files is `qmlscene`.

You just need to change your QtQuick version to 2.0 since the Ubuntu SDK is using Qt 5:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
```

Visit http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/qml/ for further examples.